# Divide array of chars into tokens

Tags: c

I have to check if strings given by the user are correct expressions. The strings should look like this:

```
int1+int2+int3+int4+...
```

for example:

```
1+5+21
```

Is a correct expression, while 1+a is not.

How can I do that?

---

The problem I encountered is that I define strings like:

```
char *str;
str = (char*)malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
char **output = strtok(str, "+"); // error
```

So I get segmentation fault when using `strtok` function.

Comment: `strtok` `return`s a `char *`, not a `char **`.

Comment: Tokenize by `strtok` is not suitable for such validation. E.g `1+++5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of using `strtok`, in your case:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int function()
{
     char* str = malloc(80);
     strcpy(str,"1+5+21");

     const char s[2] = "+";
     char *token;

     token = strtok(str, s); /* get the first token (1) */

     while( token != NULL )  /* walk through other tokens */
     {
         // characters manipulation for verification
     }

     free(str);

     return(0);
}
```